# Drawing a rectangle under text on image Then save

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm currently working on camera app. I have achieved to write text on image but there is a problem that sometimes it's hard to read text just because of the dark colors of the picture. So I want to draw a white rectangle under text.

Actually I found how to draw a rectangle into picture but I couldn't draw it under text and also after saving the rectangle does not appear.

[image: MainStoryBoard Picture]

The code below is for drawing rectangle:

```
     let imageSize = CGSize(width: ImageDisplayWidthConstantSize*0.75, height: 50)
     let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 215), size: imageSize))
     self.view.addSubview(imageView)
     let imageBlank = drawCustomImage(imageSize)
     imageView.image = imageBlank

    func drawCustomImage(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    // Setup our context
    let bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
    let opaque = true
    let scale: CGFloat = 0
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, opaque, scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Setup complete, do drawing here
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 50)

    CGContextStrokeRect(context, bounds)

    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds))
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds))
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds))
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds))
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    // Drawing complete, retrieve the finished image and cleanup
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

and this code is for inserting text on the picture:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let ScreenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let ImageDisplayWidthConstantSize = ScreenSize.width

        let imageSize = CGSize(width: ImageDisplayWidthConstantSize*0.75, height: 50)
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 215), size: imageSize))
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        let imageBlank = drawCustomImage(imageSize)
        imageView.image = imageBlank

        image = textToImage(CustomerTextBox.text!, inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 50, y: 0)) //Customer Text Field
        image = textToImage(ResponsibleTextBox.text!, inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 1000, y: 0)) //Responsible Text Field
        image = textToImage(LocationTextBox.text!, inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 2200, y: 0)) //Location Text Field
        image = textToImage(DescriptionTextBox.text!, inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 50, y: 200)) //Description Text Field

        ImageDisplay.image = image


    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func textToImage(drawText: NSString, inImage: UIImage, atPoint:CGPoint)->UIImage{

    // Setup the font specific variables
    let textColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let textFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 100)!

    //Setup the image context using the passed image.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(inImage.size)

    //Setups up the font attributes that will be later used to dictate how the text should be drawn
    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
        ]

    //Put the image into a rectangle as large as the original image.
    inImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height))

    // Creating a point within the space that is as bit as the image.
    let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(atPoint.x, atPoint.y, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)

    //Now Draw the text into an image.

    drawText.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    // Create a new image out of the images we have created
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    // End the context now that we have the image we need
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //And pass it back up to the caller.
    return newImage
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your function instead of writing new one. Just copy paste function `textToImage` and change its name. Then use white color with white background and change size. So you'll get white rectangular box. Here is the example of the code what I'm saying.

```
func drawRectangular(drawText: NSString, inImage: UIImage, atPoint:CGPoint)->UIImage{

// Setup the font specific variables
let textColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
let textFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 400)!

//Setup the image context using the passed image.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(inImage.size)

//Setups up the font attributes that will be later used to dictate how the text should be drawn
let textFontAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
    NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white 
    ]

//Put the image into a rectangle as large as the original image.
inImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height))

// Creating a point within the space that is as bit as the image.
let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(atPoint.x, atPoint.y, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)

//Now Draw the text into an image.

drawText.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

// Create a new image out of the images we have created
let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
// End the context now that we have the image we need
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//And pass it back up to the caller.
return newImage
}
```

Then call this function:

```
image = drawRectangular("___________", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 50, y: 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution, just add to textFontAttributes 
NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white (Swift 3). Swift 2 UIColor.whiteColor()

```
let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
        NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white 
        ]
```

And now you can call the function textToImage to draw the text and the rectangle[image]